# Flask render_template IndentationError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I write some code like

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    t = "!!!!!!"
    return render_template('hello.html', title=t)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

also i have hello.html template in templates folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p> {{ title }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run it I get error

```
  File "webui-controller.py", line 9
    return render_template('hello.html', title=t)
```

But when I run without title argument (`return render_template('hello.html')`) it works fine. How can I solve it?

Comment: This happens because you somehow changed the indentation of the line (for example, replacing spaces with a tab or vice-versa) while editing. The problem will not show up in the code in the question, because Stack Overflow converts tabs to spaces in formatted code. Please see the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code runs fine on my setup: Flask 1.0.2 and python 3.6.5. Look at your set up, maybe use a virtualenv with the previously mentioned versions.

Comment: My setup is Python 3.7.0 and  Flask 1.0.2